# How does refreshObject work in nested managed object contexts?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data

Say I have an object on a parent, main queue concurrency type, and I change one of its property values. Then, without saving, I execute a fetch request on a child, private queue type, to fetch an array where that object is included. The issue I'm having is that sometimes the object I get does not have the pending changes included that were made on the main thread, although it should.

However, if I call `[childMOC refreshObject:object mergeChanges:YES];`, I do get pending changes. But the description in the documentation says that this method

> "Updates the persistent properties of a managed object to use the
>   latest values from the persistent store.

" Wouldn't these values then be the values that are saved to disk, so it would not include any pending changes?

I'm a little confused as to how this method works..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With nested managed object contexts, child context will not see any changes made directly to the parent context. You will always need to refresh your object in child context if you want the latest changes.

And yes, refreshing includes pending changes from the parent context. The docs need update in that regard.

The change propagation goes automatically (when saving) only from child -> parent context.